# Выделяется ли запятыми слово "вообще"?

Tags: пунктуация

-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выделяется, если это вводное слово.
Например: *"Вообще, я не вполне понял это выражение"*.
Но оно может и не быть вводным, как, например: *"Это вообще не то, что я хотел"*.